# Specify the master database of a link server in "use <<master db of a link server >> go " in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I just want to know how to include the master db of a link server in SQL Server's `USE`. I performed the query below but it produces and error:

```
USE [192.168.1.2].master
GO
```

I already created the link server using this working query before generated the code above

```
DECLARE @TargetServer varchar(255) =  '192.168.1.2' 

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE name = @TargetServer)
    EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver @TargetServer, 'droplogins'
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
        @server = @TargetServer, 
        @provider = N'SQLNCLI', 
        @datasrc = N'tcp:192.168.1.2', 
        @srvproduct = N'',
        @catalog = N'master';


    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
        @rmtsrvname = @TargetServer, -- has to match the server name in sp_addlinkedserver
        @useself = N'False',
        @rmtuser = 'LapuLapu',
        @rmtpassword = 'HunkNgMactan';
END
GO
```

Thank you and I will appreciate each response.

P.S. Sorry for my English grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all your linked server already "looks" into `master` database.

When you want to use in your query some objects from other databases, just use fully qualified object names like this:

```
select *
from [192.168.1.2].db1.dbo.tab1 join [192.168.1.2].db2.dbo.tab2
...
```

If you still want to use `use` in your code, you can use `exec ...at ...` passing into `exec()` everything you want:

```
exec ('use my_db; select db_name()') at [192.168.1.2]
```

Linked server should be configured for RPC out in the last case.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. it is now working :)

I followed your advice regarding exec and also set up the RPC out for the linked server